# Trouble with ArcGIS Server 10.2 web adaptor when Amazon Image start/stop

Tags: arcgis-server, amazon-ec2, arcgis-web-adaptor

Every time we stop our ArcGIS Server 10.2 Amazon Image we need to reconfigure the web adaptor.  Anybody have the same trouble or know of a solution?

Comment: Have you installed the ArcGIS Server software on a fresh Windows AMI from Amazon or do you use Esri prepared AMI? Are you on Windows or Linux? You could probably update your answer; I have a couple of suggestions but I'll wait for the details. PS. Do you understand that restarting a stopped instance results in a new IP address?

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar issue, but it had nothing to do with Amazon.  So just in case you're having the same issue...

We run the web adaptor in Tomcat deployed as a Windows service.  But the Tomcat service always started up faster than the ArcGIS Server service.  As it turns out, if Tomcat starts before ArcGIS Server, then the web adaptor is broken until you restart Tomcat.

For us, the fix was to make the Tomcat service have ArcGIS Server as a dependency.  From and elevated command prompt I did this:

```
sc config Tomcat7 depend= "Tcpip/Afd/ArcGIS Server"
```

(And yes, the weird spacing is absolutely necessary.)  This makes Tomcat wait for ArcGIS Server before it even attempts to start up.

After that everything always worked fine after restarts.

Comment: It seems that we don't have tomcat running as a service.  Did you do any special configuration of tomcat before running the command above?  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: No Tomcat service, eh?  It sounds like my answer just doesn't apply to your setup.  (I've never run ArcGIS in EC2, by the way, so forgive me if this was a wild goose chase.  I thought I'd post it since your problem sounded a lot like what we saw.)  But to directly answer your question: my Tomcat is pretty close to what you get right out of the box from the "32-bit/64-bit Windows Service Installer" from this URL: http://tomcat.apache.org/download-70.cgi.  I didn't do anything during its setup that would affect the command line above.